# Flash on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, safari, adobe-flash

Flash is not supported in OS X Lion i.e. Safari, how can I browse webpages with flash content and actually view the flash content?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adobe Flash Player is supported in Lion (Chrome works by using its own copy of the plug-in that you can disable) and Safari uses the Plug-in installed in your personal libraries folder:

```
~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
```

or in the system-wide libraries:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
```

Lion, however, doesn't ship with Flash player installed by default (I'm not 100% sure because I haven't had Flash in a long time), but that doesn't stop you from installing it.

Head over to [Adobe's FlashPlayer download page](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/) and select 10.4-10.6 as your operating system:

[image: Flash Player Download]

So as you can see there is not a 10.7 version yet, so there are some issues. At first it was said that Lion disabled the Hardware acceleration of Flash; Adobe later retracted that when they found out it was their own bug.

> The final release of Mac OS X Lion (10.7) provides the same support
>   for Flash hardware video acceleration as Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6).
>   The previous “Known Issue” described in a tech note suggesting that
>   video hardware acceleration was disabled in Lion was incorrect and
>   based on tests with a pre-release version of Mac OS X Lion that
>   related to only one particular Mac GPU configuration.

<sub>source: [Adobe's Blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/07/correction-regarding-hardware-acceleration-of-flash-player-on-mac-os-x-lion.html)</sub>

If you are brave enough, you could try the BETA version (used by developers) that is theoretically the version that will be released for Lion.

Those Betas are available [Here](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer11.html).

Comment: Downloaded the Flash Plugin from Adobe's Download Page & it worked fine thanks. FYI The plugin installed is the 10.7 beta version by default x x x

Comment: Glad it worked Samantha! Remember that the beta is a little bit rough yet according to Adobe :)

Answer (score 0):

Were did you heard that Flash is not supported in Lion?

Flash is very well supported, I have it running in Safari and Chrome and it works fine.

Comment: Well... "Fine". It's flash we're talking about; so I'd say it works like in Snow Leopard.

Comment: Adobe has released a document with known issues of their products when running OS X Lion & flash is one of them. You can scan every file in your system, there is no flash & you can't download it since Adobe only support up to Snow Leopard.http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/905/cpsid_90508.html